# Sub Navigation Moving

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I created a navigation that has a horizontal submenu. For some reason when I rollover over submenu the top nav is moving.

http://jsfiddle.net/pgorski/2kBru/ - Sub menu is located on the product link.

I search the site but could not find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `border: 1px solid transparent;` to your links

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2kBru/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your border set to your a tag. Remember that each border will produce 1px more over the original  tag you used. So the tab when you hover your mouse on will be bigger than the original tab. Try removing the border and test it.